# Leaving a button disabled after app restart

Tags: android

My app has a button that disables if the day is the same day that it was clicked before, but if I reboot the app the button goes back online even if the day is the one to disable it.

```
shDayMed = sh.getInt("daymed", calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
int day = shDayMed;
int dayAtual = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if (day != dayAtual) {
    save.setEnabled(true);
    pesohj.setEnabled(true);
} else {
    save.setEnabled(false);
    pesohj.setEnabled(false);
}
```

I believe this is the wrong part, if the day is not the current day, should set the button true, but its doing the opposite...

Comment: Where are you storing the day it was clicked? That piece of code is missing.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Post your data save method.

Answer (score 1):

Store the last date clicked in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) then when you start the `Activity`, retrieve the value to determine if the button should be disabled or enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) if you want to keep track of a value even if the app is closed and restarted. The variables you put in the code will be deleted when the app is closed.

Save the variable to shared preferences like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDeafaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit()
editor.putInt("Day", Calendar.DAY_OF_THE_MONTH);
editor.apply()
```

and then retrieve it using:

```
int dayAtual = sharedPrefs.getInt("Day", -1 /* this is the default value if the pref isn't found*/)
```

Hope this helped you.